# Is ordering by a key necessary for paging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I read that when executing a `TOP` query without an `ORDER BY` that the results returned by the SQL Server may differ between executions because it's not guaranteed that you receive the same top x values due to the missing sorting.

I wondered if it is the same in the following sample:

In a table `person` there are columns `id`, `name` and `age`. The table contains thousands of rows, but all persons have the same age. The id is unique.

I now want to page through this table with a page size of e.g. 20 and order by age.

```
SELECT *
FROM person
ORDER BY age
   -- ,id     -- is this necessary?
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

Does the same issue occur as with the `TOP` clause because the condition that it is ordered by matches a lot more records than the page size? Do I have to additionaly order by `id` to make sure that when going through the pages that every record occurs exactly once?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93988/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `ORDER BY` is *the* control you have to tell the server what ordering guarantees you want it to provide. Anything you fail to say in the `ORDER BY` clause is fair game for the system to fail to respect.

For dependable paging<sup>1</sup>, you need to ensure that you have enough expressions in your `ORDER BY` clause so that every row's position will be *uniquely* defined. For a single table `SELECT`, this is most easily achieved by including all primary key column(s) after any other ordering criteria.

---

<sup>1</sup>But note that this still assumes that the data in the table is *static*. Getting "once and only once" display of data when using paging and facing the possibilities of inserts, updates and deletes can be tricky and often here you'll wind up accepting the occasional paging mishap.

Comment: I think your side note is just as important. It's not only about the ordering, but also that the result set can change between the paging queries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Id will help to a certain extent but regardless of how you page, SQL select statements are not deterministic so
you cannot make assumptions of uniqueness across query executions.

Comment: They are deterministic if the data is static and you provide sufficient expressions in your `ORDER BY` clause to *ensure* that they're deterministic. It cannot violate your `ORDER BY` clause if its acting correctly and it's not deliberately *trying* to cause people issues.